# Derangements of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> How many ways can the integers $\{1, . . . , 5\}$ be arranged so that
>   exactly $2$ of elements are in their natural position? Can you
>   generalize this to the integers $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ so that $r \leq n$
>   of the elements are in their natural position?

Well, There are ${5 \choose 2}$ to choose the two integers that are in their natural position and the other $3$ integers should not be in their natural position so we have $d(3)$.

So the answer is ${5 \choose 2}d(3)$

Now in general, the answer should be $${n \choose r} d(n-r)$$

Is that correct reasoning

Comment: What does d(3) mean?

Comment: derangements of $3$ numbers

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is correct.

Comment: In that case, the answer is correct. It's a bit harder to actually compute out  d(n)